# How send attachemts from ms outlook to opentext?

Tags: outlook, integration, opentext

I neet to send email's attachemnts to OpenText. How can I do that? Is there some tools to solve tihs situation whithout export file to file system and then upload this files to OpenText?

Comment: If your using Content Server, you could use Enterprise Connect.  Link is to OpenText customer portal (Requires login) https://knowledge.opentext.com/knowledge/cs.dll?func=ll&objId=16476546&objAction=browse&sort=name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see two options in order to save attachments to Content Server:

1) As said, you can install Enterprise Connect to all clients. With this component the users have to do some manual job (chose where to save the attachment, every time).

2) Using elink and a workflow. This case is usefull if you have a specific location where to save attachments. The only action needed by the user is the forward of the email to the elink folder.

cu